# What is the meaning of `public string this[string columnName]` When implementing IDataErrorInfo interface?

Tags: c#, wpf, indexer, idataerrorinfo

What is the meaning of `public string this[string columnName]` When implementing IDataErrorInfo interface?

```
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Name":
                    return ValidateName();
                case "PhoneNumber":
                    return ValidatePhoneNumber();
                default:
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't get it why there are square parentheses and what it does.

---

**Answer:**
Thanks to Hans and Scott now I know that is simply the syntax of an indexer. More information [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexer).

Comment: What specifically do you not understand the `this[string columnName]` syntax or are you asking why they do it at all?

Comment: Look in your favorite C# language book for "indexer".

Comment: You have to understand IDataErrorInfo, and then you will understand the meaning of This[columnName], and I think this is why you got a downvote.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: the syntax. I don't get it why there are square parentheses and what id does.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: this was closed????

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is a [C# indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), it lets you use your class like

```
IDataErrorInfo myClass = new MyClass();
string phoneNumberErrorInfo = myClass["PhoneNumber"];`
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted me, what about my answer was incorrect or not useful? I can't fix my question if you don't tell me what I have done wrong.